# how to display path in our next activity on itemselect in listview

Tags: android

```
public class Lucenconcept extends Activity {
    Button   btn1;
    EditText mEdit;
    String txt2;
    public ListAdapter adapter;
    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        File index = new File("/sdcard/index/");
        index.mkdir();

        mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);


        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
                IndexSearcher indexSearcher;
                try {
                    indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher("/sdcard/index/");
                    QueryParser parser = new  QueryParser("text", analyzer);
                    Hits hits = indexSearcher.search( parser.parse("("+ "text:" +mEdit.getText().toString() + ")"));
                    String txt2[] =new String[100];
                    String txt="";

                    for (int i = 0; i < hits.length(); i++) {
                        Document hitDoc = hits.doc(i);
                        Log.i("TestAndroidLuceneActivity", "Lucene: " +hitDoc.get("title")+ hitDoc.get("path"));
                        txt=hitDoc.get("title");
                        txt2[i]=txt;      
                        String location=hitDoc.get("path");
                   }
                   lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter
                        <String>
                        (Lucenconcept.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,txt2));
                        indexSearcher.close();
                } 
        });
    }
}
```

I m able show title on list view I want to display path   `hitDoc.get("path")` from this string on item selct in next activity ..

Cud any one plz help meam not able to display url in next activty while I have put all the think manifest and all the I think there is mistake in postion  plz help me..

Answer (score 0):

Use `Intent` for passing data between activities

Refer [Intent](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2007/12/playing-with-intents.html) example